# Can't link libraries for C++11 on MacOS Mojave

Tags: c++, macos, boost, cmake, openssl

I'm having trouble getting boost/openssl to link to my C++ project in CLion. I'm trying to build my program in CLion by clicking build, although I've also been trying to just manually compile with g++ but to no avail. My CMakeLists.txt looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(FinalProject)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

# Set OpenSSL dir, this should be default on linux/mac
set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR, /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl)

# Get OpenSSL
find_package(openssl REQUIRED)

# Get cppRestSDK
find_package(cpprestsdk REQUIRED)

find_package(boost REQUIRED)



# Compile + Link
add_executable(FinalProject main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(FinalProject cpprestsdk::cpprest)
```

I've tried changing

```
target_link_libraries(FinalProject cpprestsdk::cpprest)
```

to

```
target_link_libraries(FinalProject boost ssl cpprestsdk::cpprest)
```

and many other variations to ensure that all the dependencies I'm using get loaded (OpenSSL, cpprestsdk, and Boost) however I can't seem to get any of these to work as I keep getting various errors like:

```
"library not found for "-lssl", "-lboost", "-lopenssl"
```

I installed openssl using homebrew but when I run `homebrew link openssl` I get: `"Refusing to link macOS-provided software: openssl"` and adding `--force` gives me the same error message.

I've created symbolic links in the paths [mentioned here](https://medium.com/@timmykko/using-openssl-library-with-macos-sierra-7807cfd47892) but to no avail.

Running the CMakeLists.txt with just the `target_link_libraries(FinalProject cpprestsdk::cpprest)` gives me:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::system::detail::system_category_ncx()", referenced from:
      boost::system::system_category() in main.cpp.o
  "boost::system::detail::generic_category_ncx()", referenced from:
      boost::system::generic_category() in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

But I can't figure out why since it *seems* Boost is loading fine (I get the message "Boost Version 1.68" when I build with `target_link_libraries(FinalProject PRIVATE cpprestsdk::cpprest boost)` but I also get the error `ld: library not found for -lboost`).

In my main.cpp (only file with code) I'm including:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/filestream.h>
#include  "openssl/bio.h"
#include  "openssl/ssl.h"
#include  "openssl/err.h"
```

Anyone know what I'm missing? I'm guessing it's something simple in my CMakeLists.txt, but not sure. My only OpenSSL version is 1.0.2q and I'm on MacOS Mojave. Running openssl in my terminal does work, so it appears to be in my PATH. Really at a loss here as I'm not sure what's wrong at this point. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Just a suggestion: Tackle one problem at a time. First, one of the libraries, then cmake, then the other library. Firstly, that reduces the size of each problem. Secondly, it is required for posting here, because asking two or three questions at once is frowned upon and also because you then automatically have the required [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify that you want from boost. Here, you need "system":

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED system)
```

Boost sets up variables to help after:

```
target_link_libraries(FinalProject ssl cpprestsdk::cpprest ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY})
```